# Laravel eloquent: group the related models (e.g. all the comments for collection of posts)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

To get the comments for a single Post: `Post::find(1)->comments()`

To get multiple Posts: `Post::whereBetween('id',[1,10])`

How to get all the combined comments for multiple Posts?
A la `Post::whereBetween('id',[1,10])->comments()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$posts = Post::whereBetween('id',[1,10])->with('comments')->get();
```

Or if you wont to get only comments

```
$comments = App\Comment::whereHas('post', function ($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('id', [1, 10]);
})->get();
```

Or if related primary key post_id

```
$comments = App\Comment::whereBetween('post_id', [1, 10])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reverse solution: get the Comments and filter by related Post.

Comment: I suggest you use 3-rd solution, because it is query only one table, but first and second solutions use join tables which is more hard query

Answer (score 2):

Use `pluck()`:

```php
$posts = Post::whereBetween('id', [1, 10])->with('comments')->get();
$comments = $posts->pluck('comments')->flatten();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the comments, and assuming you have a *post_id* field in your Comment model, and you have the ids of the posts as you've indicated:

```
$comments = Comment::whereIn('post_id', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])->get();
```